# Vertical "fractions" with more than 2 parts

Tags: custom-notation, boxes

Standard `FractionBox` syntax allows only 2 arguments and creates 2-part fraction for numerator and denominator.

Is it possible to draw similar construction, but with more than 2 parts? Some sort of column with separators only between inner parts?

The following code

```
Column[{"x", 200, Integrate[Sin[x^2], x]}, Alignment -> Center, Dividers -> Center]
```

draws best what I found but it does dividers of similar length in entire column. I would like dividers to accommodate two adjacent parts only.

Comment: Yes, I have custom expressions which I want to have such custom syntax.

Comment: I'm not totally clear on what you want. Could you describe why nested `FractionBox`es aren't suitable? For instance, `Fold[FractionBox, x, Range[5]] // DisplayForm`

Comment: @Oleksandr I think the problem with that is the shrinking point size.

Answer (score 5):

Interesting question.  I don't have much experience with this sort of thing so I imagine there is a better way but this is what I could hack together at the moment:

```
frac[lst_List] := Column[
  Column /@ Partition[Riffle[lst, \[HorizontalLine]], 2, 2, -1, {}], 
  Alignment -> Center, Spacings -> 0]

{"x", 200, Integrate[Sin[x^2], x]} // frac
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Here is another approach, probably closer to "correct":

```
frac2[lst_List] :=
  Style[Fold[FractionBox, #, {##2}], ScriptSizeMultipliers -> 1] & @@
    (ToBoxes@Style[#, ScriptSizeMultipliers -> 0.71] & /@ lst) // DisplayForm

{"x", 200, Integrate[Sin[x^2], x]} // frac2
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

I am assuming that you want expressions at any tier of the notation to be the same size.  If you are fine with them shrinking as they go up then a much simpler form can be used without `Style` and `ScriptSizeMultipliers`:

```
frac3[lst_List] :=
  Fold[FractionBox, #, {##2}] & @@ (ToBoxes /@ lst) // DisplayForm

{"x", 200, Integrate[Sin[x^2], x], Integrate[Sin[x^2], x]} // frac3
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will learn of your examples! First ones are better (without shrinking).

Comment: @Suzan You're welcome, but you may want to leave this question open (no Accepted answer) for a while longer.  I am hardly an expert at output formatting.

Comment: Ok will wait for other points...

Comment: For `ScriptSizeMultipliers` less than one you might like to also add `ScriptMinSize`. Also `ScriptLevel -> 1` may or may not be preferrable. The OP might like to try it out.

Comment: @Mike Thanks for the tips; I'll try them out later.  Or, you could post your own answer if you prefer.

Comment: my suggestion is really just rounding out your answer. Doesn't warrant a separate answer.